# I am trying to get urls from Bing search API, but getting this kind of error

Tags: java, api, bing

I am creating an article summarization project however I am a beginner in java and cannot fix the error. What I am trying to do is get the URL's from Bing search API for custom query which I can later summarize.

```
package Summarizer;


import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.core4j.Enumerable;
import org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumer;
import org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers;
import org.odata4j.consumer.behaviors.OClientBehaviors;
import org.odata4j.core.OEntity;
import org.odata4j.core.OQueryRequest;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Safer
 */
public class Crawler {
    ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    String qry;
    int count = 10;
    public Crawler(String qry) {
        this.qry = qry;
        getURL();
        printToFile();
    }
    public Crawler(String qry, int count) {
        this.qry = qry;
        this.count = count;
        getURL();
        printToFile();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Crawler crawller = new Crawler("paris attack");
        crawller.getURL();
        crawller.printToFile();

    }
    public void getURL() {
        qry = "\'" + qry + "\'";
        //System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "172.31.1.4");
        //System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
        ODataConsumer c = ODataConsumers.newBuilder("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search").setClientBehaviors(OClientBehaviors.basicAuth("accountKey", "I/JMZMShDneSQBg6o+21hcz5eEjR4ROyxnFwG1K4iRM")).build();
        OQueryRequest<OEntity> oRequest = c.getEntities("Web").custom("Query", qry);

        Enumerable<OEntity> entities = oRequest.execute();
        Iterator i = entities.iterator();

        while (i.hasNext() && count > 0) {
            String[] fields = i.next().toString().split("OProperty");
            String link = fields[fields.length - 1].split(",")[2];
            links.add(link.substring(0, link.length() - 2));
            System.out.println(link.substring(0, link.length() - 2));
            count --;
        }

    }
    public void printToFile() {
        System.out.println(links.size());
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("URL\\urlfile.txt");
            for (int i = 0 ; i < links.size() ; i ++) {
                out.println(links.get(i));
            }
            out.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

i expect the output to generate the summary of the links from bing search api but couldn't fetch the url 
and i am getting this kinda error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:128)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:457)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:557)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$300(WebResource.java:69)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.method(WebResource.java:539)
    at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyClient.doRequest(ODataJerseyClient.java:143)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataClient.getMetadata(AbstractODataClient.java:43)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer$CachedEdmDataServices.refreshDelegate(AbstractODataConsumer.java:212)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer$CachedEdmDataServices.getDelegate(AbstractODataConsumer.java:205)
    at org.odata4j.internal.EdmDataServicesDecorator.findEdmEntitySet(EdmDataServicesDecorator.java:46)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer$CachedEdmDataServices.findEdmEntitySet(AbstractODataConsumer.java:221)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer.getFeedCustomizationMapping(AbstractODataConsumer.java:235)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer.getEntities(AbstractODataConsumer.java:73)
    at org.odata4j.consumer.AbstractODataConsumer.getEntities(AbstractODataConsumer.java:69)
    at Summarizer.Crawler.getURL(Crawler.java:51)
    at Summarizer.Crawler.<init>(Crawler.java:37)
    at Summarizer.Summary.<init>(Summary.java:30)
    at GUI.Base.jButton3ActionPerformed(Base.java:344)
    at GUI.Base.access$3(Base.java:331)
    at GUI.Base$4.actionPerformed(Base.java:135)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:215)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:126)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: try limiting the number of entries you are trying to retrieve using the top(int top) method. http://odata4j.org/v/0.7/javadoc/org/odata4j/core/OQueryRequest.html